# Label features on hover/click with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, labeling, qgis-2

Simple question: Is there a built in/easy way to show labels for features based on a hover or click action with QGIS 2.0.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a feature called map tips that does exactly that.

[image]

They can be activated in the display tab of the layer properties, you can display a field value or use HTML code. Check out Nathan's [blog post](http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/html-map-tips-in-qgis/) for more info.

Comment: Blog post link is broken (2020), you can check out the documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#maptips

Comment: Alternatively and archived version of the missing page. https://web.archive.org/web/20190728092648/http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/html-map-tips-in-qgis/