# How to show text display from two layers in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, maptips

I have two layers. I want to show text display from two layers when mouse hover on layer. It can be ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Label features on hover/click with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86130/label-features-on-hover-click-with-qgis)

Comment: @Taras thanks ~ It's from one layer but I want two layers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open feature request: [Option to have Map Tips display on all layers](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/7051). It's six years old, and the only recent activity is from a year ago, when its status was changed to "not an easy fix."

So it looks like the answer to your question is, unfortunately, no.

Probably the closest you can get is by using the Identify tool.